Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))
I've tried to install Wine but appears this warning, and it blocks the installation.
I've also tried to delete it but it doesn't work T_T

apt-key is deprecated, here is how to install wine on elementary OS 7.0 "Horus" based on Ubuntu 22.04:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Installation guide
